# After downloading Ubuntu installer, it asked me to reboot for install. It shut down and seemingly rebooted into a black screen!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, software-installation, uefi, shutdown

So for my recent project I decided to install Linux Ubuntu on a separate 60GB SSD to dual boot with Windows 8.1. Once I went on the official Ubuntu website and downloaded the free version of Ubuntu I ran the installer and with out much "installing" (meaning, without selection of new boot drive etc.) it asked me to reboot my machine, "now" or "later" I wasn't questioning it much so I simply clicked "reboot machine now". So it did its thing, shut down and rebooted as I had anticipated, but as it turns out it got stuck on a black screen (computer was still running) without any sort of error message, nada!

Then I tried to reboot manually again hoping to, perhaps entering the BIOS but as it turns out, my keyboard only activates or turns on after the BIOS loading screen, where it says "hold F2 or dlt to enter UEFI BIOS" which essentially didn't work. Now I'm completely powerless because I can't do anything with this computer simply because I don't know what it wrong.

Comment: How did you install? Did you select Alongside, Replace or Something else?

Answer (score 0):

I had a small problem that can be of help to you: HDMI, there is some problem with HDMI that if its not correctly configured after installation it will stay black all the time,my advice is to switch to VGA and see if the problem continues.

Comment: Both my monitors are already connected via VGA, Thank you very much for you answer either way!